# Execute Script daily, only between 6 AM & 6 PM

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I have a 32 scripts setup to run every 5 minutes, the scripts use the gmail API so I'm running into some API request limitation issues.

Is there a way to make the scripts run only between a certain time period?

Basically:
Every 5 minutes, daily between 6 AM & 6 PM CST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function runDuringDayTime() {
  var start=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate()).valueOf();
  var sixam=21600000;
  var sixpm=64800000;
  var current=new Date().valueOf();
  var diff=current-start;
  if(diff>sixam && diff<sixpm) {
    //call you function here
  }
}
```